# Im trying to create an equation that uses the time till the end of the month as a variable.. any sugestions?

Tags: php, mysql

When a user creates an account I have to manually activate some of its functionality (which I want). What I need to happen after its activation is take $someTIMEvar (days, min, seconds any will work) till the end of the month UPDATE/SET a DB entry. Then use $newTIMEvar (the DB entry) in an equation. After the end of the month this process dose not need to happen again.. any suggestions?

EDIT -- Ill try to be more clear. using my code

```
<?php
$end = strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')) - 1; 
$now = time(); 
$numSecondsUntilEnd = $end - $now;

$num =  $dollar / $TOTAL_seconds_IN_month;//How do I get this as a function of the current month?
$new_num = $num * $numSecondsUntilEnd;
?>
```

How do I get it to only happen once.. then at the end of the month not happen again.. ?

Comment: Do you need month end unix timestamp ? i.e. in seconds

Comment: Im using $end = strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')) - 1;
    $now = time();
    $numSecondsUntilEnd = $end - $now;
    echo $numSecondsUntilEnd;

Comment: My issue is.. hot do I only do this once...

Comment: $numSecondUntilEnd = strtotime('last day of this month 23:59:59') - time(); // In Seconds

Comment: Can you explain more to understand what exactly you want ?? If above is not like that.

Comment: If you have to do it on a per user basis, you need to run a query. With that in mind, why not simply add a boolean flag to the sql table?

Comment: @enhzflep thats fine... how would that be helpful? maybe I dont understand boolean flags well enough?? I already have user accounts set to activate functions based on an IF/ELSE $someVAR == 'active' or <> 'active'

Comment: Do you want this not to happen end of this month only ??? i.e. manual functionality ? If yes, you can hardcode the month value

Comment: @PankajGarg after the end of the month I do not want the above script to run again... I only want the above to happen with new accounts and only in the first month..

Comment: I think Ill just run a cron job and clear the second stamp once a month....

Comment: @Nan - simple. Just add a flag eg. specialProcessDone. Set the flag to false when you create the user. When it comes to the end of the month, check the flag - if it's false, do the required thing then set the flag to true. Simple as. There may be better ways, though if you're asking such a question, I have a sneaking suspicion you're not managing a site with millions of members. You could just run a query at the end of the month that returned all users whose flag was set to false, process them and then wait again till next month to process any new members.

Answer (score 0):

Use a setting in database for the month after that you dont want to run that part of code. So that you can check like

```
//if(time() < strtotime('MONTH_Setting_IN_DB 23:59:59'))
```

Or If you don't have any problem in hard coding than you can put the month in your code like :

```
if(time() < strtotime('April 2014 23:59:59')) {
    // execute your code under this condition
}
```